# Can Teamviewer be run without installing on a Mac for controlling another machine?

Tags: remote-control

In Windows you can choose to just run the executable without installing it but I don't see this option in the Mac installer.
You can run the TV Quicksupport module on the host on Mac without installing but I am asking about the controlling side.
Before I have used TV via a web browser but this option appears to have been deprecated now.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  What does success look like. Run team viewer on your Mac to control a remote device or os?  You might need to edit your post if it gets closed or no answers show up.

Comment: To control a remote macOS install yes. I think the question is pretty clear about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The following is based on information gathered from the [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/) web site and running the corresponding downloads for each:**

- Under *Windows*, **TeamViewer** Installation options, using **TeamViewer_Setup.exe**, are:

  - Basic installation
  - Installation to access this computer remotely (unattended)
  - Run only (one time use)
- Under *macOS*, **TeamViewer** requires installation to use it.

  - The, **TeamViewer.dmg** file contains the **Install TeamViewer.pkg**, which is an installer, not the **TeamViewer.app** that gets installed by running the installer package.
- Under *Windows* and *macOS*, **TeamViewer Host** requires installation to use it.

  - Under *Windows*, the **TeamViewer_Host_Setup.exe** installs **TeamViewer Host**.
  - Under *macOS*, the **TeamViewerHost.dmg** file contains the **Install TeamViewerHost.pkg** file, which is an installer, not the **TeamViewerHost.app** that gets installed by running the installer package.
- Under *Windows* and *macOS*, **TeamViewer QuickSupport** does not requires installation to use it.

  - Under *Windows*, the **TeamViewerQS.exe** can be run directly after downloading it and does not install.
  - Under *macOS*, the **TeamViewerQS.dmg** file contains the **TeamViewerQS.app** which can just be doubled-clicked to run the application, and does not install.
- Under *Windows*, **TeamViewer Portable** does not requires installation to use it.

  - **TeamViewer Portable** is not available for *macOS*.

Comment: I see. In reality in Windows you use the same executable to install and run TV without installing it.
It is a pity that this is not the same case for Mac.